# JQueryUI: Place dialog box where mouse is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates, screen-resolution

I want to place the jquery dialog box where the user clicks on the screen.

so far I have:

```
$("#something").click(function(e){
    $("#myDialog").dialog( "option", "position", [e.pageX,e.pageY]);
    $("#myDialog").dialog('open');
});
```

But this doesnt work due to some page scrolling issues. I suspect it would work if I didnt have to scroll the page down to get to the element with id="something" that I click.
I think that this is because the Y (height) position is the whole page position rather than the viewable area.

Is there a way to either grab the viewable area XY co-ords or calculate the size of the viewable area and do some funky maths to correct the page XY co-ords?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#something").click(function(e)
{
    var x =e.pageX -$(document).scrollLeft();
    var y =e.pageY -$(document).scrollTop();
    $("#myDialog").dialog( "option", "position", [x,y]);
    $("#myDialog").dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: actually, on debugging, the result is x=4 y=677. yet the jquery dialog shows at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I have solved this. You had the scrollLeft and scrollTop on the wrong way around. I have edited.